# Movesense direct access to GATT endpoints

Tags: gatt, movesense

I am trying to read ECG real-time data from a movesense sensor by using another generic BT-LE module.

GATT characteristics can be used for Heart Rate (read or notify) or other predefined services : we simply send a raw command to an endpoint, for example a 0x0100 (START_NOTIFY) on the corresponding UUID for a heart rate notification streaming.

The problem is that with a micro controller and a BT LE module we can not use any of the C, Java, React... libraries since all of the underlying code is not open source ( the movesense device-lib and community-lib do define how to use and program the services, but we can not discover what to send on one of the 2 other services that are defined, the UART service or the Unknown Service, which are probably used by the movesense library to send all of the URL requests).

As a footnote, we access our generic BT-LE module with AT UART commands to communicate to the movesense platform.

Thanks for any help or guidance,
FS

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/samples/ble_std_services/CustomBleController.cpp

```
void CustomBleController::OnUartData(uint8_t * p_data, uint16_t length)
```

for receiving and

```
send_ble_nus_data(buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
```

to send using NUS (Nordic UART service).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do your own GATT service on Movesense sensor (since v. 1.6.0) using the CustomGATTService module. Please look into latest movesense-device-lib and the sample "custom_gattsvc_app" (and with 2.0, the "gatt_sensordata_app")

*Full Disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*